# Why wont my python list be inserted into my SQLITE database from a loop?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-insert

I am having a very confusing time, I want to add default data to my table from a python list. However it fails every time to add the list data, but I can add hard coded data using the for loop I just don't see why it doesn't work with the list data.

**this works, and updates the db:**

```
categories=["test 1","test 2","test 3","test 4"]

cur = db.cursor()
for category in categories:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO CATEGORIES (name) VALUES ('category')")
                    
db.commit()
cur.close()
```

**this doesnt work:**

```
categories=["test 1","test 2","test 3","test 4"]

cur = db.cursor()
for category in categories:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO CATEGORIES (name) VALUES (?)",category)
                    
db.commit()
cur.close()
```

My CATEGORIES table has an id set to auto increment and the a name column. I am beyond confused. Would love some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap the category in an 1-tuple (and you'd have an N-tuple for N parameters in a query).

```py
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES (name TEXT)")

categories = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4"]
print("Inserting...")
cur = db.cursor()
for category in categories:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO CATEGORIES (name) VALUES (?)", (category,))
db.commit()
print("Retrieving...")
for row in db.execute("SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES"):
    print(row)
```

prints out

```
Inserting...
Retrieving...
('test 1',)
('test 2',)
('test 3',)
('test 4',)
```

A more succinct way to write this would be to use `executemany`.

The generator `((cat,) for cat in categories)` does the same tuple-wrapping here.

```py
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES (name TEXT)")

categories = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4"]
print("Inserting...")
db.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO CATEGORIES (name) VALUES (?)",
    ((cat,) for cat in categories),
)
db.commit()
print("Retrieving...")
for row in db.execute("SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES"):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Great thank you this worked, just so I understand correctly for the future. When inserting from a list, should the list be a list of tuples (in best practice)?

Comment: Yes, since e.g. `INSERT INTO CATEGORIES (name, something_else)` would be input as `[(name1, something1), (name2, something2), (name3, something3)]` – there's no special case for only a single variable.

Comment: Thanks you all is working great now, thanks for ending my confusing its been about a 24hours worth of googling and staring at my screen wondering why.